# Laptop connected to Office VPN. Unable to connect to spring eureka services

Tags: spring, vpn, netflix-eureka

My laptop is connected to my office VPN network and when I start eureka server,conifg, 4 client services in local environment all are registered with Eureka with IP:PORT.

Something like : 192.x.x.x:config-service:9091

With this configuration my Spring cloud gateway not able to connect to downstream services (other 2 client service) on 192.x.x.x IP.

Everything seems normal when I do not use the VPN and work from office location.

Example: :config-service:9091

In this case, gateway is able to locate and connect with downstream services.

Any idea why services are not located by gateway when I am connected to my office VPN?

Answer (score 0):

When you connect to VPN, your IP address will get changed.
Suppose you are connecting to Wifi without VPN then your ip address might look like 192.XX.XX.XX then once you connect with VPN then it will change from wifi to Ethernet IP address or something else.

Check your ipconfig if you have multiple IP based on configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You should renew dhcp lease when you are connected vpn and your apps running.

[click link for macos example screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpGpy.png)